# Android KeyguardManager not returning any result

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

I am trying to implement `KeyManager' into my app. When authorized action is needed, user is prompted with pattern for unlock. I observe result of this in my activity and based on result I proceed to further action. Following is code I am using,

```
 private const val RESULT_OK = 99
 val km = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
 val i = km.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent("Name", "Something")
 i?.let { ind ->
                startActivityForResult(ind, RESULT_OK)
               // startActivityForResult(Intent(this@LoginActivity, AnotherActivity::class.java), RESULT_OK) //This works
            }

  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        Log.i("TAG======", requestCode.toString() + "--" + resultCode.toString())

    }
```

Whenever I am using `startActivityForResult(ind, RESULT_OK)` onActivityResult is not called but when I used any other activity like `startActivityForResult(Intent(this@LoginActivity, AnotherActivity::class.java), RESULT_OK)` , onActivityResult is getting called after activity is finished. Am I missing something? I am testing this on physical device (OnePlus 5t) running Android 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after 2 hours of debugging ! This was happening because I was using  `RESULT_OK` constant as `private`. As soon as I made it public, my `KeyManager` was working properly! I assume system was taking it as a `0` and hence it was not returning anything to activity :)